# What killed my tomcat service and how can I restart it automatically?

Tags: tomcat, service, ubuntu-18.04

tomcat 9 with ubuntu 18.04. tomcat service status:

```
● tomcat.service - Tomcat 9 servlet container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Thu 2020-03-26 03:00:31 UTC; 3h 33min ago
  Process: 8815 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8858 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8865 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
```

catalina.out says nothing. syslog says

```
Mar 26 03:00:31 user systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Mar 26 03:00:31 user systemd[1]: tomcat.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Mar 26 03:17:08 user systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 26 03:17:08 user systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

The service was dead but manually restarting the service succeeded.

What can I check in order to know what killed tomcat?

What can I do to restart tomcat in case something like that happens in the future?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless a cruel sysadmin gave it `kill -9`, I would suspect that Linux kernel's OOM (Out of memory killer) did kill the process. Check if `dmesg` hints towards that direction. If so, inspect if your server has enough RAM for the tomcat to run comfortably and/or if you could tune the tomcat memory settings.

Comment: Thanks. where can I check this "Check if dmesg hints towards that direction"? Yesterday there was enough ram but now I remembered that clamav is running at 3 so this may have caused this. How can I restart tomcat in case such thing happens?

Comment: Dmsg is in /var/log/ how to automatically restart is part of sysctl. Although you should not automatically restart until you understand the problem.

Comment: You can also check kern.log using: 

tail -100 /var/log/kern.log 

Look out for lines similar to: 

"Out of memory: Killed process 519 (java) total-vm:2534060kB, anon-rss:579552kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:997 pgtables:1660kB oom_score_adj:0"